# Name validation with special conditions using regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate the Name in Java that will allow following special characters for single time {,-.'}. I am able to achieve with the Expression that will allow user to enter only such special characters in a string. But I am not able to figure it out how to add restrictions where users cannot add these characters more then one time. I tried to achieve it using quantifiers but remain unsuccessful. I have done the following code yet!

```
Pattern validator = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z+\\.+\\-+\\'+\\,]+$");
```

Comment: Can you post some example strings

Comment: @vks here are examples (John O’Malley-Smith)(John O’Malley-Smith)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookahead assertion in your regex:

```
Pattern validator = Pattern.compile(
  "^(?!(?:.*?\\.){2})(?!(?:.*?'){2})(?!(?:.*?,){2})(?!(?:.*?-){2})[a-zA-Z .',-]+$");
```

`(?!(?:.*?[.',-]){2})` is a negative lookahead that means don't allow more than 1 of those characters in character class.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wN7sW5/2)

Comment: but its validating "John O’Malley-Smith" as false!

Comment: Because that string has a space and wrong quote `’`. , see my updated answer

Comment: still validation John O’Malley-Smith as false. can you please make it like it will allow {. ' - .} for single time. Allow alphabets with spaces

Comment: Perfect achieved with the following                                                                Pattern validator = Pattern.compile("^(?!(?:.*?\\.){2})(?!(?:.*?\\'){2})(?!(?:.*?\\-){2})(?!(?:.*?\\,){2})[a-zA-Z .',-]+$");

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can just take into account names where such characters would only happen once. Names like "Jonathan's", "Thoms-Damm", "Thoms,Jon", "jonathan.thoms". In practice for names, I don't think that such special characters would occur at the edges of the string. As such, you can probably get away with a regex like:

Pattern validator = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[-',\.][a-zA-Z]+)?$");

This regex should match a regular ASCII name followed optionally by a single "special" character with another name after it.